# Tomcat project is giving ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag in Wildfly 13

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, wildfly

We try to deploy [pwm-project](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm) in Wildfly 13 and we are interested in `Server WAR` implementation. The project has been developed and tested in Apache Tomcat 8.0.33. We have succeeded in running on Tomcat 9.0.21 too. But when we deploy the same war file in Wildfly 13, we are getting an exception like:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;Z)V
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:889)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:818)
    at jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.configguide_002dstart_jsp._jspService(configguide_002dstart_jsp.java:1154)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
    at password.pwm.http.servlet.configguide.ConfigGuideUtils.forwardToJSP(ConfigGuideUtils.java:177)
    at password.pwm.http.servlet.configguide.ConfigGuideServlet.nextStep(ConfigGuideServlet.java:148)
    at password.pwm.http.servlet.ControlledPwmServlet.processAction(ControlledPwmServlet.java:189)
    at password.pwm.http.servlet.AbstractPwmServlet.handleRequest(AbstractPwmServlet.java:125)
    at password.pwm.http.servlet.AbstractPwmServlet.doGet(AbstractPwmServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter$PwmFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:155)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.ConfigAccessFilter.processFilter(ConfigAccessFilter.java:81)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter$PwmFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:155)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AuthenticationFilter.processFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter$PwmFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:155)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.SessionFilter.processFilter(SessionFilter.java:112)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter$PwmFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:155)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.ApplicationModeFilter.processFilter(ApplicationModeFilter.java:84)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter$PwmFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:155)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.ObsoleteUrlFilter.processFilter(ObsoleteUrlFilter.java:67)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.AbstractPwmFilter.doFilter(AbstractPwmFilter.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.RequestInitializationFilter.initializeServletRequest(RequestInitializationFilter.java:244)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.RequestInitializationFilter.doFilter(RequestInitializationFilter.java:166)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at password.pwm.http.filter.CookieManagementFilter.doFilter(CookieManagementFilter.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.releaseTag(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;Z)V
    at jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.configguide_002dstart_jsp._jspService(configguide_002dstart_jsp.java:236)
    ... 101 more
```

As I search this exception, this is because of Wildfly JSP compiler. But I don't know how to solve it. Some resources suggest removing servlet-api.jar. Can the problem be with container dependencies in [pom.xml](https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm/blob/master/server/pom.xml)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have seen this error too, hes having problem with Jasper, so try this two things man: Maven force update, if it doesn't work, try removing dependency of Jasper and updating project, after that add it again and re update.

Comment: where is the dependency of Jasper? @DanielV

Comment: In the pom, do ctrl+f and search "jasper"

Comment: How did it go mate?

Comment: There is just one dependency about Jasper and it is related with one-jar. But I have tried after I removed. Nothing changed. There is a thread here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/263579 @BugsForBreakfast

Comment: I see, to be honest with you I don't know whats going on at this point, but when this happened to me I found that the error was that my project had dependencies with some classes that where in another project, so sometimes accesing some of their mehtods gave me that error, hope that you can find a solution and share it with us mate, did you try removing the servlet api jar?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast there is no servlet api jar. But I remove dependencies.